# Is /dev/urandom a CSRG?

Tags: random

Can we rely on /dev/urandom on UNIX machines if we need a cryptographically secure random generator?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpouse of `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`

Answer (score 1):

From [This Site](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/):

> Both /dev/urandom and /dev/random are using the exact same CSPRNG (a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator). They only differ in very few ways that have nothing to do with “true” randomness.

Comment: You beat me to it, that site is the default reference for confusion about `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: I laughed when I read your comment.  I often have people beating me to the punch, but rarely do it to others ..  Maybe I'm slower than most ...